# TLS Downgrade error on Opera or Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, https, opera, tls

When I try to browse some secure websites on Firefox or Opera, I often get the error "ERR_TLS13_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED", while the page loads properly on Chrome.

This occurs with a lot of websites, but not all secured websites.

Is there a way to allow Opera (or Firefox) to display those websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Opera.
Goto `opera://flags/#tls13-variant` and Set `TLS 1.3` to `Enable` (Draft 23).